# Python adding median to user to odd user input

Tags: python, input, median

I'm trying to get the Median of the users given salary. Is it easy to implement it to the current code?

```
 def Lista():

    values = []
    print("Give your salary from smallest number to largerst.")
    while True:
        sum1 = int(input("Give your salary (0 ends): "))

        if sum1 == 0:
            print("Salary average:",sum(values)/len(values))
            print("Salary minimum:",min(values))
            print("Salary maximum:",max(values))
            print("Salary median:",values[len(values)/2])
            return False

        else:
            values.append(sum1)

    return Lista

Lista()
```

Can't seem to be able to do it myself.
I'd use only odd numbers of asked salary

Comment: you are overwriting `sum` in `sum = int(input("Give your salary (0 ends): "))`. so it will not do what you expect later in the code (at `sum(values)`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it wasn't sum in the original version but translated (so it's easier to read) it and didn't notice that it was overwriting it.

Comment: just in case: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the solution integer the value and the length;

```
int(values[int(len(values)/2)])
```

Also I noticed in the average that it's the only one that ends in xxxx.0, this can be edited to be the same as others by editing it like this;

```
int(sum(values)/len(values))
```

So the full code would look like this

```
def Lista():

    values = []
    print("Give your salary from smallest number to largerst.")
    while True:
        sum1 = int(input("Give your salary (0 ends): "))

        if sum1 == 0:
            print("Salary average:",int(sum(values)/len(values)))
            print("Salary minimum:",min(values))
            print("Salary maximum:",max(values))
            print("Salary median:",int(values[int(len(values)/2)]))
            return False

        else:
            values.append(sum1)

    return Lista

Lista()
```

Hopefully this helps :)
E: sum were overlapping, changed it to sum1

Comment: Thanks, in my own version I wasn't using sum, as this is a translation to get easier view of the problem.
Thanks for the reply, it works now =)